# When I've specified a header file in my code why do I need to specify a library in my gcc compilation command?

Tags: c, glfw

I am using GLFW libraries in my *.c program.

```
    #include <GL/glfw.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int running = GL_TRUE;
        int k=0;
.....
...
..
```

The command I use to compile is:

```
gcc test1.c -o test1 -lglfw
```

My question is that, since this line is present:

```
#include <GL/glfw.h>
```

why do I have to pass `-lglfw` to `gcc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GL/glfw.h is a header file, it declares all the types, constants, functions, you know the drill, it's to make the *compiler* know what code to generate and to make it not complain about unknown identifiers. libglfw is a library that contains the actual binary code (or stubs that will be bound later by the dynamic linker, or something like that), you have to link with it to make the *linker* not complain about unresolved symbols.

It's possible for the header to contain the actual *source* code of the library (so the compiler will generate the binary code over and over again for each translation unit where the library is used), it's called a header-only library then, but in the C world such libraries aren't something that you can find often and this particular library is not header-only.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifically the GLFW library. However, the `#include` is a preprocessor directive for the **compiler** (if you miss it, your code won't compile), but the `-lglfw` argument is for the **linker** (if you miss it, the code would be compiled to an object file, but you would get undefined symbols by the linker).

Some (rare) libraries are a header only things; they provide features entirely in the `#include`-d headers. I only know one such library (GNU lightning).

Most libraries exist as shared or static library files (ie `lib*.so` or `lib*.a` files). They provide features as already compiled code that you need to link into your executable.

Read more about [linkers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the header file (that with the .h) only contains declarations of say functions, variables classes and so on. So by including a header file in a .c file you make the declarations of the functions etc. known to the compiler. That means, the compiler is able to generate commands that actually call the functions.

However, the definition (i.e. the actual implementation) of a function is quite some different thing and it is (usually) *not* present in the header (which only contains declarations).

So in order to actually call into the implementation, the object code (i.e. the compiled source code) must also be present within the executable. This code, however, is contained in an external library (libglfw.a, in your case). So by adding the -lglfw option, you add the object code contained within the library to your executable which ensures that calls you make from your code will eventually find their way into the library code.

Bottom line:
*.h file -> declaration only, no implementation

*.cpp, *.o, .a(.lib), .so(.dll, .dynlib) -> object code, implementation

Comment: Often, the header `*.h` files contains source code of inlined functions (such as simple class member functions) and macros, which are "implementation" like.

Comment: Thats exactly why I put the "(usually)" there.